# Post to facebook wall from phonegap android

Tags: facebook-graph-api, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk

Am trying to post to facebook wall from an android app written with phonegap. I do get the following error: message:(#200) the user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action type:OAuthException. So my question is How do i get the user to authorize my app so i can post to their wall. I use this code to login:

```
        function login() {
            FB.login(
                function(response) {
                    if (response.session) {
                        alert('logged in');

                    } else {
                        alert('not logged in');
                    }
                },
                { perms: 'publish_stream' }
            );
        }
```

and i try to post with the below code which throws an error.

```
        function postToWall() {
            var body = 'Reading Connect JS documentation';
            FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { body: body }, function(response) {
              if (!response || response.error) {
                alert('Error occured ' + JSON.stringify(response.error));
              } else {
                alert('Post ID: ' + response);
              }
            });
          }
```

Am using the phonegap facebook api from https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect and FB.ui does not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Posting the same content throws errors so use a text type input for positioning content on Facebook, with `post` as the text type input:

```
function postdata()
{
    var body = document.getElementById("post").value;
    FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error)
        {
            alert('Error occured');
        }
        else  {
            alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are serious problems with that phonegap plugin right now. I'm really wishing it would be picked back up to fix them. One of the main issues is that oauth2 isn't supported and the plugin is using an older facebook sdk.